# Error when using REST API to Add Rows to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, rest

I'm trying to use the REST API to add data to a DE, but I am getting back a validation error when I make the call:

Call:

```
HOST: https://www.exacttargetapis.com/data/v1/async/dataextensions/key:rest_api_test/row
Content-Type: application/json 
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXX 
{ "items": [{ 
   "Email": "clark.buskey@wework.com", 
   "First Name":"Clark", 
   "Last Name" : "Buskey", 
   "ZipCode": "11201" 
}] }`
```

Error Message:

```
    {
        "resultType": "Validation",
        "resultClass": "Error",
        "resultCode": "OperationNotAllowed",
        "message": "Invalid request, this operation has not been enabled for this Account or Data Extension."
    }
```

Has anyone experienced this before?  If so, do you know how to get around it?

Comment: Hello CJ Buskey, You shared the response which says that the OperationIsNotAllowed therefore i believe it this is the reason. But you give the community no possibility to help because you did not share what you have sent to the api endpoint. Therefore please edit your post and share your rest call and make sure you do not post customer data inside the process.

Comment: This potentially could be caused if you are using async without having support turn it on for your account. Async is not activated by default, it needs to be requested (but it is free)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using the [ASYNC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/data-extensions-api.htm) version and likely have not had this turned on in your account. It is a simple solution in that you call SFMC Global Support or your SFMC Account Rep and ask them for it.  It is a free service as well, so there will be no extra cost associated with it. Or you can utilize the [SYNC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm) version, which is activated by default.

Below is straight from docs:

---

**Data Extensions Async API**

The Marketing Cloud REST API supports the ability to persist data into an identified data extension asynchronously.

> We limit these resources to accounts that are enabled via a custom
>   setting. Marketing Cloud can enable this setting at the enterprise,
>   account, or custom object level. Reach out to your account
>   representative to enable these resources in your account.